# Web link to open iphone camera app after clicking link from website?

Tags: android, html, ios, web

I'm looking for some way to either create the following or if it already exists be provided with it. After much looking I have not been able to find it. What I want is for a person to be able to scan a QR code which acts like clicking a web link (Or something else?) then for their iphone or android default camera app to open. Perhaps its a stretch but if I could turn the camera onto a selfie that would be even better.

I am NOT asking for how I can in any way have access to what shows up. I simply want to be able to open the camera app after clicking a link. If it exists I please comment it.

Comment: A QR code may contain a URL but still require on a mobile device a camera app to be scanning that particular QR code. If you want to get camera/image from a website, see: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes I know this. Apple camera app has feature for detecting QR codes from photos. I need some kind of link that the QR code represents which opens the camera app. if there is another way, the great. Preferably something like this exists and I dont need to do much if any coding.

Comment: I'm not sure what your purpose of opening the camera app if (a) it is already open doing the QR scan and (b) you don't have a website/app to handle the data. Just be aware that QR codes are just a text string and the camera app has to interpret URL. There is no universal 'executable program' that can be inside a QR code. My link explains how a website can be configured to ask the user for a camera/image which the website can then process.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Imagin for instance an instagram post of a QR code. If you screenshot it, in the photos app apple has inbuilt feature for detecting the code. So you could consieve of a insatgram post containing a QR code which from the photos app can be "clicked on". In this case I want it to open to the camera to show the persons face, unexpectedly, just as a joke/test of this idea. I can make a simple webpage if its the only way.